# Error: L3 forwarding

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to run the l3fwd sample application in DPDK took kit and I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks2Xz.png).

I enabled all the cores but still doesn't give me the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the E100 NIC does not have 4 TX queues the l3fwd app trying to configure (nb_txq=4), so it is fails.

The solution would be to run a DPDK example which require less queues or to use a NIC with at least 4 TX queues.

Comment: How can I check for the number of queues supported by NIC card. I tried using the command  $ sudo ethtool  -l eno1  It gives the below output.            
     Channel parameters for eno1:
     Cannot get device channel parameters
     : Operation not supported

Comment: Run DPDK `testpmd` application in interactive mode, i.e. `testpmd -- -i` and then run the command: `show port info 0`. Among other information, it shows  `Max possible RX/TX queues`

Comment: I tried to run `testpmd -- -i`  this command and this gives me the below error. `PMD: gntalloc: ioctl error
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Creation of mbuf pool for socket 0 failed`  As Mentioned in the resolved issues (https://dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.0/rel_notes/resolved_issues.html) I tried using `testpmd –total-num-mbufs=1500` but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Allocate more hugepages?

Comment: Initially, I allocated a huge page of 128KB. So should I be allocating more huge pages for this ?

Comment: Do `cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i huge` to check